Dynamically rendering href in DataTables with Jinja2
I am using Jinja2 with FastAPI.
I would like to use a template table made with DataTables wherein I need to customize the table values for different pages using the same template table.
In one of the tables I have to convert the data of first column into a link (href tag).
For this I use the render method of DataTables for columndefs so that in my data-table.html I have:
new DataTable('#myTable', {
    ...
    columnDefs: [{{ columndefs|e }}]
});

and in the parent template I set columndefs as local variable:
{% set columndefs = """
        {
            targets: 0,
            render: (data, type, row) => '<a href="/api/'+data+'">'+data+'</a>',
        }
    """
%}
...
{% include "data-table.html" %}

The problem is that this throws an error:
    {% set columndefs = """
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'api' is undefined

I think this is because the templating has problems by mixed use of " and '.
How can I correctly use href in columndefs so that it works?

Just a suggestion, if you've got control of the data being returned from the API (or whatever function creates the data) is to send a preformed URL rather than create it in Jinja. Been down a similar road, and while Jinja is pretty powerful, I've found having all the data and attributes ready, really simplifies the Jinja templates and makes them more maintainable and reusable.

Thanks, this is a good solution.
But meanwhile I solved it by passing the columndefs as context parameter on server side
